# Chained string manipulation in bash

Tags: regex, string, bash, variables

Given the variable

```
export TAG="1.3.2_release"
```

I want to transform the variable to the value `132`.

I cant get the substring:

```
bash-5.0$ echo ${TAG:0:5}
> 1.3.2
```

And I can replace the dots with empty string:

```
bash-5.0$ echo ${TAG//./}
> 132_release
```

But I can't combine these two operations in one line:

```
bash-5.0$ echo ${${TAG:0:5}//./}
> bash: ${${TAG:0:5}//./}: bad substitution
```

Comment: thank you both for the comment. I am not sure if  this is the same. In your mentioned post the result of a lookup is used to adress another variable. I dont want to do that. I want to use the result of a lookup and do further operation on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use the following expansion :

```
${TAG//[^0-9]/}
```

It removes every non-numeric character from the variable's value.

Comment: thank you! I like that, since i dont have a case were a number comes after the `_` this will work

Comment: @Henning Glad to be of assistance !

Answer (score 3):

Why not keep it simple and create a temp variable, which holds the first substitution value in it and then create variable which has actual substituted value like:

```
export TAG="1.3.2_release"
var="${TAG//./}"
echo "${var/_*/}"
```

Since I saw your attempt of using an external command(I mean apart from bash's) then why not simple `awk` too

```
export TAG="1.3.2_release"
echo "$TAG" | awk -F'_' '{gsub(/\./,"",$1);print $1}'
```

Comment: thank you, I might do that, I just wondered why it didnt work since it does in zsh. guess its not possible in bash

Answer (score 0):

It possible to use `cut` to get just the part in front of the first `_` instead of getting a substring of certain length:

```
bash-5.0$ echo ${TAG//./} | cut -d'_' -f 1
> 132
```

This is basically better than what I wanted because now the version name can be in variable length.

I still wonder though why my initial try didnt worked.